# Are $C^\infty$ exotic spheres $C^k$ exotic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

The only theory of exotic spheres that I know is of $C^\infty$ structures on them; that is, that there are plenty of spheres (in dimensions $n \geq 7$ that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic. To keep this question reasonable, I'll restrict to the $n=7$ case.

Are the exotic $S^7$s diffeomorphic for any $C^k$ with $k \geq 1$? Has there been any serious study about the structure of (the cobordism group of) $C^k$ exotic spheres for finite positive $k$? If so, what are some references?

Comment: I've added the [tag:homotopy-theory] tag because I'm aware that the story of exotic spheres is closely related to some questions in homotopy theory. Apologies if the tag was chosen poorly.

Comment: Since nothing interesting happens in the $C^k$ category, you might be interested in looking into the question for PL structures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any $C^k$ structure on a manifold for $k > 0$ can be uniquely promoted (modulo diffeomorphism) to a $C^\infty$ structure; furthermore, the corresponding map between $C^k$ structures modulo equivalence to $C^\infty$ structures modulo equivalence is bijective. See [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64717/smooth-structures-compatible-with-a-given-c1-structures), for example.

Comment: This is incredible! Thank you.

Comment: No thanks are necessary, but you're quite welcome.